# LARAVEL SAIL: how to solve problem with poser in laravel sail

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-sail

I started the project through laravel sail and I can't see the
view's index on localhost, when I enter the link I get the error:

target class [] does not exist.

and below that error message shows the following code, which corresponds to the index.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
*/

if (file_exists($maintenance = 
__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

/*
| Register The Auto Loader
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
| Run The Application
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

The content that I put in the view index.blade.php should be
displayed, the route was declared, the controller exists and the
above error appears

Comment: [Can I ask a question in a language other than English?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)

Comment: You can go to [pt.so]

Comment: I voted to reopen your question, but please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, you probably shouldn't have. OP has translated their question, but it should only be reopened if it is actually clear and on topic. The image makes it hard to interpret that way.

Comment: @Chris: I agree it is still unclear what the problem is. What is the exact error reported by PHP?

Comment: "I get the error in the index.php file" - what does that mean? You haven't shared any error message

Comment: target class [] does not exist